# Typed REST API with nested schemas

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am experimenting with Typescript to write full typed code that makes requests to an existing REST API. This API allows arbitrary nesting of models in the request. For simplicity, let's say we have just two models `User` and `Address` and a fake `getUser`. This is what I got:

```
interface User {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: Address;
}

interface Address {
    country: string;
    city: string;
}

type UserSelector = {
    id: null;
    name: null;
    age: null;
    address: Partial<AddressSelector>;
};

type AddressSelector = {
    country: null;
    city: null;
};

function getUser<K extends keyof UserSelector>(_fields: Pick<UserSelector, K>): Pick<User, K> {
    // return a mock object, will get from DB in real code
    return {
        id: "1",
        name: "Jean Seberg",
        age: 30,
        address: { country: "FR", city: "Paris" },
    } as Pick<User, K>;
}

const user = getUser({
    //unknownField: null, // SHOULD TYPE ERROR, IT DOES
    id: null,
    age: null,
    address: { country: null },
});

console.log(user.id, user.age, user.address.country);
//console.log(user.name); // SHOULD TYPE ERROR, IT DOES
console.log(user.address.city); // SHOULD TYPE ERROR, IT DOES NOT
```

As you can see, this is not working as as expected, `user.address.city` should give a compile type error because the key `city` is not in the address selector. It's clear why it does not work, but I don't know how to write in a generic way so that it supports any nesting level (hardcoding types with relations does not seem an option).

Is this possible in Typescript (any version). How?

Answer (score 0):

The type check is right.

```
type UserSelector = {
    id: null;
    name: null;
    age: null;
    address: Partial<AddressSelector>;
};

type AddressSelector = {
    country: null;
    city: null;
};
```

the property `address` of `UserSelector` is `Partial`， which meanings all properties of `AddressSelector` is optional, so it's ok if `city` is not show.

As your desired, you should remove `Partial` and specific the type of AddressSelector['country'] and AddressSelector['city'].

Comment: How would you write? Note that the idea is to have all types to be inferred from the selector sent to `getUser`.